# Get Status of receiver user in a chat

Tags: android, chat, smack, asmack, quickblox

I want to detect the presence of a specific user in the chat:

```
Presence presence = roster.getPresence(xxxx@xxx.xx);
System.out.println("Status receiver :" +presence);
```

How can I convert the presence variable to a String? How can I verify the value? (i.e. "Available" / "Unavailable").

Answer (score 0):

Check Presence documentation here http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/packet/Presence.html

could be something like this:

```
Presence presence = roster.getPresence(xxxx@xxx.xx);
System.out.println("Status receiver :" +presence.getStatus() );
```